# Ruby `require': cannot load such file (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
 - lib
   - yp-crawler (directory)
      - file-a.rb
      - file-b.rb
      - file-c.rb
   - yp-crawler.rb
```

My `lib/yp-crawler.rb` file looks like this:

```
require "yp-crawler/file-c"
require "yp-crawler/file-b"
require "yp-crawler/file-a"

module YPCrawler
end
```

When I try to run my file at the command line by doing this:

```
ruby lib/yp-crawler.rb
```

I get this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- yp-crawler/file-c (LoadError)
    from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from lib/yp-crawler.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: have you tried `require_relative "file-a"`?

Comment: @davidhu2000 Bruv...perfect. That worked. Add it as an answer, and I will accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to API Dock, `require_relative` is what you need.

> Ruby tries to load the library named string relative to the requiring
>   file’s path. If the file’s path cannot be determined a LoadError is
>   raised. If a file is loaded true is returned and false otherwise.

So all you have to do is

```
require_relative "file-a"
require_relative "file-b"
require_relative "file-c"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this a new change since 1.8/1.9?

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is to add the directory to `$LOAD_PATH` (this is how most of the gems require files).
`$LOAD_PATH` (aka `$:`) is where ruby looks for a file when you call `require`.

So you can try this code

```
# lib/yp-crawler.rb

$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
# it can be $LOAD_PATH.push also

require "yp-crawler/file-c"
require "yp-crawler/file-b"
require "yp-crawler/file-a"

module YPCrawler
end
```

*P.S.*
For example you can [see](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/paperclip.gemspec#L1) how paperclip does the same thing.

Comment: I was just going to post this.